# Can I call external urls using cron.yaml in Google AppEngine and Can I include sleep() in it?

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to call external urls using cron job of Google App Engine. And I also want to induce sleep between cron jobs.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly fetch external URLs using a cron job, but this is easy to work around: Just define a cron job that, as it sole activity, fetches an external URL using the [urlfetch API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/).

Sleeping inside a request is possible as long as it doesn't exceed 30 seconds of execution time, but generally a very bad idea. Instead, use the [task queue](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) with a delay so the task will execute when you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

If you sleep inside the job, you can run out of time just like a regular request (see [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html)):

> A URL invoked by cron is subject to
>   the same limits and quotas as a normal
>   HTTP request, including the request
>   time limit.

So you will probably want to use the scheduling to approximate a sleep call.  So if you want to sleep for two minute, use:

```
every 2 minutes
```